# Fill not staying true to outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Apologies if this has been answered before, but after searching I still cannot find a solution.

What could be causing the following issue?

[image: Illustrator weird path/fill issues]

Notice how the fills are not staying true toe the outline.  I have looked into similar issues like "align to pixel grid" and others but none has fixed the problem.  The issue is magnified especially when you scale them down to very small sizes.

Comment: This is kind of a shot in the dark, but since CC 2014 I think, GPU preview has been the source of many graphical glitches. Which I seem to accidentally enable all the time, because the hotkey is same as export in Indesign (`Cmd+E`).

Answer (score 1):

I simply expanded the object and the issue disappears...

Comment: strokes or filters might play into this - or even sub-pixel rendering issues.